# How do you install a project's peer dependencies with just npm or yarn?

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg

Or is there no command for doing so? In which case, I would have to use something like [install-peerdeps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/install-peerdeps).

Comment: Unless something has changed in a more recent version of npm or yarn, it seems that you would in fact need something like the `install-peerdeps` package to do this automatically. From the readme of install-peerdeps: "Starting with NPM v3.0, peer dependencies are not automatically installed on npm install, and it can be a hassle to install them all manually. The install-peerdeps tool makes the process fast and easy."

Comment: That's ridiculous. Wonder why that's the case. Thanks!

Comment: I guess some people might prefer to use `npm link` or something. But this definitely seems like it would be a useful command to have built-in.